# how to declare methods in child vue component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

child.vue:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class Child extends Vue {
  public func(): void {
    //
  }
}
</script>
```

parent.vue:

```
<template>
  <child ref="child" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
  import Child from './child.vue'

  export default Parent extends Vue {
    public create (): void {
    (this.$refs.child as typeof Child).func()
  }
}
```

TSLint error:

```
Property 'func' does not exist on type 'Component<DefaultData<never>, DefaultMethods<never>, DefaultComputed, DefaultProps>'.
```

how can let 'typeof Child' be detected as class Child? I know create a extra interface and  then import it can solve this, but is there an other way?

Answer (score 0):

First: You forgot the `@Component` decorator on your parent component. It won't type it correctly.

Second (optional): you can use the `@Ref` decorator to keep a typed reference of your `ref`.

Third: you don't need the `typeof` keyword.

```js
@Ref('child')
readonly childComponent: Child

created () {
   // Correctly typed
   this.childComponent.func()
}
```

Comment: I just realized it's an error message from Vetur validation service in VSCode but not TSLint, disable Vetur validation for ts, error disappeared,  whatever refs.child is declared as Child or 'typeof Child', or sth else.

Comment: Vetur is just showing error messages from typescript compiler, because TS can't read .vue files. If you try to actually compile, you will see that error again.